# Return user input from search bar. Flask does not parse request

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to return the users input from my search bar into a database and generate a table based on user input. However, flask prints error1.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage1():
    try:    
        if request.method == "POST":
            x = request.form
            print(x)
            name =x['search']
            a = name.split(" ",1)
            firstname, lastname = (a[0], a[1])
            print(firstname)
            print(lastname)
            c,conn = connection()
            qry = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Location FROM posts WHERE FirstName LIKE (%s) AND LastName like (%s)"
            c.execute(qry, ((thwart(firstname)), (thwart(lastname)),))
            conn.commit()
            data = c.fetchall()
            conn.close()
            return render_template("index.html", data=data)
        else: print('error1')
        return render_template("review.html")
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10%; margin-left: 25%">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">     
        <div class="row">
            <div id="logo" class="text-center">
                <form role="form" id="form-buscar">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="1" class="form-control" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter First Name, Last Name..." required/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" method = "POST" id="search" onclick="fetchlist()" >
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search                                


function fetchlist() {
    if (document.getElementById('search').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'none';

}
```

My tags are closed, but Stackoverflow wont allow me to submit

Comment: `error1` is being printed when request is not using the `POST` method. So this code simply means that request is not using the `POST` method

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm a newbie, request is not using the post method? Like sending the request to a db?

Comment: Can you post the html code from where you are submitting the data of searchbar?

Comment: I've updated the original post with the HTML

Comment: Can you also post `fetchlist()` ?

Comment: updated to include the js.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
<form role="form" id="form-buscar">
```

to

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="form-buscar">
```

Comment: You tried this? I guess  everything is okay in the code after this. Its working for me in a project of mine.